# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, json, facebook-graph-api, serialization, windows-store-apps

Im getting this exception. I don't understand what should i do. I have googled a lot but found nothing.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[LU.FacebookStalker.StoreApp.ViewModel.PageLike]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g.
>   [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET
>   type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type
>   like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object.

This is my class:

```
        public class PageLike
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string count { get; set; }
            public string photoUrl { get; set; }
        }

        public class Hangout
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string photoUrl { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
        }

        public class Interaction
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string photoUrl { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
        }

        public class Place
        {
            public object Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string photoUrl { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
        }

        public class HomeSummaryResult
        {
            public List<Hangout> hangouts { get; set; }
            public List<Interaction> interactions { get; set; }
            public List<PageLike> likes { get; set; }
            public List<Place> places { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public HomeSummaryResult HomeSummaryResult { get; set; }                
        }
```

I am calling service like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string url = string.Format("");             
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
dynamic likesResult= await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();           
var x = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(likesResult.ToString()))["HomeSummaryResult"];
likesList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<PageLike>>(x.ToString());
```

And my JSON is:

```
{
  "HomeSummaryResult": {
    "hangouts": [
      {
        "Id": "112",
        "Name": "Mohsin",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/112\/picture",
        "count": 12
      },
      {
        "Id": "103",
        "Name": "Khan",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/103\/picture",
        "count": 11
      }
    ],
    "interactions": [
      {
        "Id": "724",
        "Name": "Jawad Shareef",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/724\/picture",
        "count": 482
      },
      {
        "Id": "583",
        "Name": "Ahsan Aziz Abbasi",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/583\/picture",
        "count": 228
      }
    ],
    "likes": [
      {
        "Id": "122",
        "Name": "Community",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/122\/picture",
        "count": 324
      },
      {
        "Id": "110",
        "Name": "Musician\/band",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/110\/picture",
        "count": 119
      }
    ],
    "places": [
      {
        "Id": null,
        "Name": "Local business",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/\/picture",
        "count": 69
      },
      {
        "Id": null,
        "Name": "City",
        "photoUrl": "graph.facebook.com\/\/picture",
        "count": 43
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you assigning some sort of `ObservableCollection` in any of the parameters and are you serializing the object of `HomeSummaryResult` or some other class

Comment: Please show the code calling the deserialization code, as well as the JSON in question.

Comment: please provide the code where you are converting/passing json data

Comment: Thanks for editing your question.  We need to see your JSON also.

Comment: Sorry i added all information you requested.

Comment: I am also stuck with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the answer. I got it solved myself.

I just added `["likes"]`

Code is:

```
var x = (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(likesResult.ToString()))["HomeSummaryResult"]["likes"];
```

because json was in array.